# Bash source doesn't bail out on errexit, any possible reason?

Tags: bash

I couldn't explain what happens in my scripts, could anyone shed some light please?

I am doing some pretty standard stuff, set errexit, sourcing one script from another, catching errors and eventually bailing out if any.

s1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
num=1
if [ $num -eq 1 ]; then
    FOO="$(set -o | grep -e "errexit" -e "nounset" | grep off >&2)"
    VAR="SOME/TEXT/$(basename "$UNBOUND_VARIABLE")"
    RET="$(echo $?)"
    #ERR="$UNBOUND_VARIABLE" # this will be trapped and source will exit at this line
    BAR="LAST_IS_GOOD"
fi
```

s2.sh

```
function source_all
{
    local __f
    set -exu
    for __f in ${@}; do
        case "$__f" in
            "s1.sh" ) set -o posix; (source "$(pwd)/$__f") || return 1; echo "$$ $?" >&2 ;;
        esac
    done
    set +eux +o posix
}

function main
{
    source_all s1.sh || return 1
}

main
```

output

```
+ for __f in ${@}
+ case "$__f" in
+ set -o posix
++ pwd
+ source (blah/blah)/s1.sh
++ num=1
++ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+++ set -o
+++ grep -e errexit -e nounset
+++ grep off
++ FOO=
(blah/blah)/s1.sh: line 6: UNBOUND_VARIABLE: unbound variable # should exit
++ VAR=SOME/TEXT/
+++ echo 1
++ RET=1
++ BAR=LAST_IS_GOOD 
+ echo '9568 0'
9568 0
+ set +eux +o posix
```

source --help

```
    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

*question is:* why `source` invoked in s2.sh doesn't return 1? Why does it keep processing s1.sh after UNBOUND_VARIABLE?

thanks for your inputs

Comment: thanks: updated the question. question is: why source invoked in s2.sh doesn't return 1? Why does it keep processing s1.sh after UNBOUND_VARIABLE?

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. Minimal helps much.

Comment: You got a [Useless use of echo](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo) award: `RET="$(echo $?)"`

Comment: yup is to show that there is an error - debug only reason. thanks

Comment: For a minimal reproducible example I could remove the `source_all` function, but I left it to leave some context of the real scenario, not following very well the reported behaviour I am not sure 100% that "for loop" and "case in" do not have any impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UNBOUND VARIABLE error comes because you are using `set -u` are referencing with `$UNBOUND_VARIABLE` a variable named _UNBOUND_VARIABLE_ which has not been assigned to, in the statement

```
VAR="SOME/TEXT/$(basename "$UNBOUND_VARIABLE")"
```

. The `set -e` **does** have an effect, in that the subshell this is executed, i.e.

```
(source "$(pwd)/$__f")
```

is aborted. While the subshell due this abort indeed returns with non-zero exit code, but this does not trigger an exit of the parent process, because you have a `|| return` to the right. For the same reason, the command

```
false || echo x
```

would not terminate the execution, even though a single

```
false
```

would.

Comment: Thanks! I did some experiment - you are right. Can't tell how much helpful was this, I was being completely blind and ignoring boolean expressions.